# Installing OpenMDAO

Tags: python, terminal, installation, versions, openmdao

I am trying to install OpenMDAO, which is an open source framework that uses python. So before I get to it, it needs 3 packages:

1. Fortran Compiler
2. NumPY
3. ScyPy

Which I did install using homebrew:

```
brew install gfortran
sudo easy_install-2.6 pip
sudo pip-2.6 install numpy
sudo pip-2.6 install scipy
```

Now, to install OpenMDAO, I'm supposed to be in the OpenMDAO folder and at that level I should run this script:

```
python go-openmdao-dev.py
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: the following prerequisites could not be imported: ['scipy'].
```

So I was talking to the people at OpenMDAO, and it seems that I need to use is python2.6 - although I'm not certain, so my guess is that all the packages I installed are for python 2.7 which I downloaded since it was recommended in the python website.

The one that comes with Mac was not. So when I type in terminal the following:

```
python2.6
```

It actually runs that version. So at this point I don't know if I have to go run the script in python 2.6, but if so, I have no idea how to do it. I tried doing this and it did not work:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

If anyone is familiar with the environment or just with python itself and has any suggestions, I'll really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem after downloading scipy from a .dmg. I uninstalled, and then reinstalled from source: http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.12.0/ and then the openmdao installer recognized scipy.

This may be useful (from INSTALL.txt in scipy-0.12.0.tar.gz):

> To test SciPy after installation (highly recommended), execute in
>   Python
>
> >>> import scipy
>      >>> scipy.test()
>
> To run the full test suite use
>
> >>> scipy.test('full')
>
> Please note that you must have version 0.10 or later of the 'nose'
>   test framework installed in order to run the tests.  More information
>   about nose is available on the website__.
>
> __ http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered on the OpenMDAO support forum: 
http://openmdao.org/forum/questions/744/error-the-following-prerequisites-could-not-be-imported-scipy

The solution was to install scipy and numpy for python2.7. The original poster first installed them for python2.6, but then ran the go-openmdao.py script with python2.7. Once all the pre-reqs were installed for 2.7, it worked.